# Multirobot with one master using different namespaces

Tags: ros, turtlebot, namespace, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

This is a follow up question from question [60760 multirobot-interaction-using-turtlebot](http://answers.ros.org/question/60760/multirobot-interaction-using-turtlebot/).

When I implemented the advice on that question, which indicated that each turtlebot should run on its own namespace, I got the following errors in these 3 processes:

```
process[robot_pose_ekf-6]: started with pid [23337]
[ERROR] [1371052770.749560864]: No analyzers initialzed in AnalyzerGroup /turtlebot246/diagnostic_aggregator/analyzers
[ERROR] [1371052770.751441041]: Analyzer group for diagnostic aggregator failed to initialize!

process[cmd_vel_mux-7]: started with pid [23350]
[ERROR] [1371052771.860666093]: CmdVelMux : configuration file not found []

process[bumper2pointcloud-8]: started with pid [23386]
[ERROR] [1371052772.502205005]: Kobuki : no device port given on the parameter server (e.g. /dev/ttyUSB0)[/turtlebot246/mobile_base].
[ERROR] [1371052772.502885732]: Kobuki : could not initialise! Please restart.
```

How can I fix these errors?

The master is the workstation and both robots connect to it. I am trying to start each robot in a different namespace like this:

```
ROS_NAMESPACE=turtlebot246 roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch
```

Without the namespace assignment the robots function properly (as long as there is only one active at a time).

Thank you very much,

Rafael

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64942/multirobot-with-one-master-using-different-namespaces/) by [Rafael](https://answers.ros.org/users/5062/rafael/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't help you much because I don't have a turtlebot to test, so I hope other people can chime in.

In general, remapping often brings bugs into the light with code that hasn't been tested in a multi robot scenario. :-)

Some general advice:

- Some of your errors look like they are caused by missing parameters. When a node is called "foo", it expects its private parameters to be at "foo/...". Now if you remap the namespaces, the nodes get pushed down to "namespace/foo" and expect their parameters there. Try to do a `rosparam dump tmp.yaml` with and without remapping and try to spot the differences (and missing differences). Better restart the master in between to clear out the parameters.
- TF isn't affected by remapping, so you need to set the `tf_prefix` parameter for all nodes that use TF. But your errors don't seem to be related to TF (that will start later, when you connect a second Turtlebot). Some code even doesn't support `tf_prefix`. For instance, we've only patched that support into `robot_pose_ekf` last month, so you'll have to wait for the next release of the navigation stack (1.10.4) before you can use multiple instances of `robot_pose_ekf` at once. Or build it from source, of course.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rafael](https://answers.ros.org/users/5062/rafael/) on 2013-06-13**:
Hi Martin, thanks again for your answer. The only difference is related with the error in the second process. The one with the assigned namespace reads:
turtlebot246:

- cmd_vel_mux: {yaml_cfg_file: ''}
  Should I set this file directly in the parameters? how do I find out which file to set? Thx